# How to get the buttons in a 'dialog.showMessageBoxSync' to work in Electron.js

Tags: javascript, electron

In my electron application, I have a .showMessageBoxSync  message box with two buttons that displays if the user doesn't have a internet connection or not. The message box itself works, but the buttons on the box won't fire the functions like it is supposed to. When I click "Try again please" button, the box just closes. It does the same with the other button. I'd like to test the internet connection again if the user would like to, so I tried to call the 'execute()' method again, but to no avail.

Here is my code -

```
function secondOnline(user_callback){

    const message = () => {
        return dialog.showMessageBoxSync(null, {
            title:"Connection Status",
            message:"No internet available, do you want to try again?",
            type:'warning',
            buttons:["Try again please","No, thanks"]
        }, (result) => {
            if(result === 0){
                execute();
            }
        })
    };

    const secondMessage = () => {
        return dialog.showMessageBoxSync({
            title:"Connection Status",
            message:"Internet connected.",
            type:'info'})
    };
    const execute = () => {
        if(navigator.onLine){
            secondMessage()
        }else{
            message();
        }
    };
    execute();
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Also getting the same issue :(